# Python -- Including Duplicates in re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract all titles from an Amazon HTML source. The problem I have is that when I do `re.findall()`, it doesn't keep duplicate titles.

Is there a way to keep duplicate titles with `re.findall()` ?

Comment: Could you please post a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the master of regex, but when I use `re.findall()` I see duplicates. Post your code and we will have something to work with.

```
import re
string = "Give me an example, me an example"
re.findall('me', string)
>>> ['me', 'me']
```

Comment: If it keeps the duplicates, then my question has been answered . I just find it strange that it did not find a book title which was identical to another one . Thank you everybody :)